# Does redshift store failed queries?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I wish to analyze the queries executed on certain redshift warehouse (not mine). 
In order to do so I'm using a query with a join on stl_querytext and stl_query.

My question is how come I'm also getting illegal queries (I.E queries with wrong sql syntax)? 
When I've tried it in my local redshift I haven't seen those. Also, couldn't find relevant documentation.

Is this a configuration issue? And in case I'm supposed to those queries is there a way to know those are illegal ones?

Thanks,
Nir.

Comment: I wonder whether you could use [SVL_QUERY_METRICS_SUMMARY - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVL_QUERY_METRICS_SUMMARY.html) to determine whether the query failed?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - umm, don't see any indication there whether the query was completed successfully or not.

Comment: Correct, but you might be able to use some of the statistics (eg number of rows) to make an assumption about whether it was successful.

Comment: well, this doesn't sound very deterministic...

Answer (score 0):

So stl_querytext breaks long queries into parts identified by sequence number.  I hope you are reconstructing the parts into the original query as a first step.  This can be done with listagg() function as long as the resulting query doesn't over the max tex field (about 320 parts).

Now this is not enough to get valid SQL back in all cases because you need to treat combining the parts differently depending if the section of the query is inside or outside a text string in the query.  (Is white space needed between parts or not)

I've done this exact process a bunch so this is doable.  I don't have a perfect process on the whitespace question, I get close.  Maybe others know the expression to get an exact recreation of the query from stl_querytext.

Comment: thanks @Bill. I'm rebuilding the query using the sequence and listagg. In my personal redshift it worked fine for the scenarios. However, in the customer account it seems like we're also getting illegal queries. So I mostly wonder about what is stored in the table itself.

Comment: The table (stl_querytext) will store the newlines in the query as '\n' (2 chars).  These characters will need to be replace and when these happen outside of strings they can be replaced by any whitespace character.  If the newlines are within strings you will want to keep these are newlines.  So a regexp_replace is needed to make this change.  regexp_replace(text,'\\\\n*',chr(10)) works for me.

Also, in your listagg what character, if any, is being used to join the strings together?  Inserting character here could create failures as well.